# Set cookie in CodeIgniter that expires at specific time

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

I need to set a cookie in CodeIgniter that expires at midnight on the same day it was set. According to their cookie documentation, you set the expire time in seconds; you can't provide a specific date and time.

Is there any other way to set a cookie and provide a specific date and time, or do I really need to calculate the difference in seconds from now until midnight tonight?

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate the time, which is the number of seconds until the cookie should expire. It's easier than you probably think:

```
$expire = strtotime('midnight') - time();
```

If you have the date helper loaded, replace `time()` with `now()`.